# How to remove DBnull value from lambda query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, lambda

i have this query

```
        DataSetTest DB = new DataSetTest();
        DataSetTestTableAdapters.TESTTableAdapter ADPT = new DataSetTestTableAdapters.TESTTableAdapter();
        ADPT.Fill(DB.TEST);

         try
        {
            var xx = DB.TEST.Where(s => s.Name != null).Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = ex;
        }
```

But it give me this error

```
{"The value for column 'Name' in table 'TEST' is DBNull."}
```

so how can i allow DBnull value in the list or remove it many thanks in advance fro any help

Comment: To check for `DbNull` you can use `Convert.IsDBNull(s.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all i have finger it out just use `IsNameNull()` method

```
var xx = DB.TEST.Where(s => !s.IsNameNull()).Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xx = DB.TEST.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(s.Name))).Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: it give me this error {"The value for column 'Name' in table 'TEST' is DBNull."}

Comment: Convert.ToString() convert to value as NULL if DB is giving NULL it will not give you an error and here where clause is used to check if it is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xx = DB.TEST.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Name.ToString())).Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

When`s.Name` is `DBNull` then `ToString()` will return `string.Empty`

Comment: Missing 1 closing after the ToString()) <- add )